# How to loop through object key values and nested values

Tags: javascript

I don't think "nested values" is the right term, but here's what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    title: 'Foo',
    content: {
        top: 'Bar',
        bottom: 'Baz'
    }
}
```

And I want to check if either title or content.top or content.bottom contains a certain string.

I've found that I can loop through an object keys with something like this:

```
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

But what if the key is an object in itself and contains other keys? What if those keys are also objects with different keys? So basically, is there a way to search the entire object in a "deep" way, so that it searches all values no matter how deep the values are "nested"?

Comment: Do you want to loop through every value? Or do you know exactly which one you need? If you know the exact property, you can use dot notation, eg `myObject.content.top`

Comment: Yeah I do want to loop through all the values, because I'm working with different objects with different values (and they're many, so manually adding them is unpractical)

Comment: What do you want returned? And only find first match?

Comment: I have an array with a lot of objects, and would like another array returned, with all the objects that contain a certain string.

Comment: Lots of solutions if you do a [site search - javascript object deep search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dobject+deep+search)

Comment: Yeah I saw those, but didn't think those were what I neeed. I'll have a look again, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested objects form a recursive data structure called a tree, and a tree is easily browsable with recursive functions. Recursive functions are functions that call themselves, like the following `browse` function :

```js
var tree = {
  a: "azerty",
  child: {
    q: "qwerty"
  }
};

browse(tree);

function browse (tree) {
  for (var k in tree) {
    if (isTree(tree[k])) {
      browse(tree[k]);
    } else {
      console.log(k, tree[k]);
    }
  }
}

function isTree (x) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Object]";
}
```

However, this function is designed to perform the same task over and over. A more generic approach would be to outsource operations applied to each leaf :

```js
var tree = {
  a: 'azerty',
  child: {
    q: 'qwerty'
  }
};

browse(tree, log);
browse(tree, searchQ);

function browse (tree, operation) {
  for (var k in tree) {
    if (isTree(tree[k])) {
      browse(tree[k], operation);
    } else {
      operation(k, tree[k]);
    }
  }
}

function log (label, leaf) {
  console.log("logged", label, leaf);
}

function searchQ (label, leaf) {
  if (leaf.indexOf('q') !== -1) {
    console.log("found", label, leaf);
  }
}

function isTree (x) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Object]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! One question though: Using this method to search through an array of  "trees", how would I return the "top" tree, rather than a nested tree? If you know what I mean..

Comment: Well, if I run the browse function the second time, the tree parameter becomes tree.child, rather than tree, right? I want to be able to return tree when a match is found. But I think I can solve this by adding a second argument to the function with which I can pass the original tree.

Comment: Basically in the searchQ function, I want it to log the "tree" variable, instead of the actual tree that contains the value.. This is because I'm looping through an array of objects and I want to return the object that contains the value, not the tree. Here you can see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/g9nnr9xu/1/. It now logs {top: "test2", bottom: "test3"} but I want it to log the tree that I pass in the forEach loop. Sorry if I'm explaining this badly.. But I can fix it with adding another parameter, so now I have it working :)

Comment: @Leon Ok I understand now. Yes you need an additional parameter. Another option would be to add a "parent" property to every child in order to be able to get to the root at any level. This is how the DOM works actually, see the `parentNode` property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode. Sorry for posting the same comment multiple times, I had to fix some inconsistencies :-)